# Powershell - Change windows 7 background to image off a website

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

```
set-itemproperty -path "HKCU:Control Panel\Desktop" -name WallPaper -value Zapotec.bmp
```

I found this code online for Powershell for windows 7, however I want the wallpaper to be set to a file stored on a webserver accessible from a browser. how would i go about doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to change my wallpaper with your command but it didn't work until I ran this: rundll32.exe user32.dll, UpdatePerUserSystemParameters. Even then, it only worked intermittently (it's a know issue on Win7).

Anyways, I have written a getfile function for PowerShell that downloads a source url to the disk.

```
function getfile($url, $filename)
{
    $wc = New-Object System.Net.WebClient

    Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $wc -EventName DownloadProgressChanged -SourceIdentifier WebClient.DownloadProgressChanged -Action { Write-Progress -Activity "Downloading: $($EventArgs.ProgressPercentage)% Completed" -Status $url -PercentComplete $EventArgs.ProgressPercentage; }

    Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $wc -EventName DownloadFileCompleted -SourceIdentifier WebClient.DownloadFileComplete -Action { Write-Host "Download Complete - $filename"; Unregister-Event -SourceIdentifier WebClient.DownloadProgressChanged; Unregister-Event -SourceIdentifier WebClient.DownloadFileComplete; }

    try
    {
        $wc.DownloadFileAsync($url, $filename)
    }
    catch [System.Net.WebException]
    {
        Write-Host("Cannot download $url")
    } 
    finally
    {   
        $wc.Dispose()
    }
}
```

You can find it and a simpler version [here](http://codealoud.blogspot.com/2011/12/downloading-files-with-powershell.html) along with a detailed description of what it is doing.

You should be able to change your wallpaper with some thing like this:

```
$url = "http://fc05.deviantart.net/fs30/f/2008/062/9/4/Serenity_WPP3___1920_Preview_by_nuaHs.jpg"
$filename = "d:\serenity.jpg"
getfile $url $filename
set-itemproperty -path "HKCU:Control Panel\Desktop" -name WallPaper -value $filename
rundll32.exe user32.dll, UpdatePerUserSystemParameters
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you can't do this. Wallpaper images must be locally stored. When you right click on an image in a browser and "set as wallpaper" it is copied to your hard disk.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have 2 options.

1. Have Powershell download the file locally and use p/invoke to call the SystemParametersInfo function in User32.dll to set the wallpaper. The API will set it and activate the change immediately. [Here's an example](http://poshcode.org/2603) of doing that.
2. Use RSS wallpaper theme. You can edit a .theme file and specify your own RSS URL, however the feed URL needs to have a media item for the images like [this one](http://themeserver.microsoft.com/default.aspx?p=Windows&c=LandScapes&m=en-US). You can download [this theme file](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/downloads/terra-dynamic-theme) and edit it with your RSS feed URL.